# Instagram Http requests

Tags: python-requests, instagram-api, decoder

I intercepted an HTTP request originating from Android to Instagram when I creating account. Here the post data that is sent to the instagram:

```
"sn_result":"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.eyJub25jZSI6IllYSnJkV3R6UUdocE1pNXBibnd4TmpRd09UWXhOakV5ZlBvUDY5UitnbmFrTzZxd1dBa0lNb0tYTVUrU3Ivd2Fzdz09IiwidGltZXN0YW1wTXMiOjE2NDA5NjE2MjAyNDYsImFwa1BhY2thZ2VOYW1lIjoiY29tLmluc3RhZ3JhbS5hbmRyb2lkIiwiYXBrRGlnZXN0U2hhMjU2IjoiYk1nR1A4VmZHWjVjRHhmREJIK2NSMlNxMitDUU92RnV5M2dlaC9jS253UT0iLCJjdHNQcm9maWxlTWF0Y2giOnRydWUsImFwa0NlcnRpZmljYXRlRGlnZXN0U2hhMjU2IjpbIm9PYnZoa3Y5UG40MFdORzBNeHB3R0V4Zng5U3AwZXY1elh3SEJkbDVtVDg9Il0sImJhc2ljSW50ZWdyaXR5Ijp0cnVlLCJldmFsdWF0aW9uVHlwZSI6IkJBU0lDIn0.GB0403seXagpVXh9uvXz0VWMq5m6xgoW-06Gn0DuENN8G5fA6qtQlW4GmMUccdR7XRbA8jRz8mb1jJmiHCnuA2RX9_O4dg-CBzP33ToSPr0kbq_gkRQ6IEyvqZHIVlm8te5tp0SVQIsdDuN4NsCuusKZdVRZt8YwfZrheOzNteXFUmK81v2S7oZiB8_A_ZJglLH2y28eS09ZKZpCGEKfashY9oey6adeHMuNHe_Gcb_x_cB-w6PQENLiN4nVMx38d8WY1tT_BZoVl1j3AszA6MuyG4tnzBVclcGfXxZWljWxmie98Y-K4hIcU0M6GBdCQtfxKtD33F5eMAbJtAqZ9A"
```

How I can decode this parameter?

Comment: `"ey"` is `{` in base 64 (`b64decode("ey==")` -> `b'{'`), which is usually a giveaway that you're dealing with encoded JSON.